# How do I show all values of a particular field when I have coded it in an expression

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-2017

[image: Preview of my report]
[image: Design view of my report]
[image: Expression for calculating % change in bottom table]
[image: Expression to show the Sort value in the bottom table]

I created a report, and I have a parameter(Sort) that allows me to choose multiple options to show the data(volume) for those options chosen. I have a second table at the bottom which has expressions, to show the % change in the values from the first table (upper table). If i choose multiple options in my parameter(Sort) and view the report, it only shows the name of the last parameter I've chosen (e.g. if i chose A, D, it shows only D) and the % change values are an aggregation of A & D values. How can i show the % change for each sort (e.g. A and the % change for A under that column, D and the % change for D under that column )

Comment: Do you have those values coming from the same dataset Or are the values for package values from two separate datasets? show your dataset sample

Comment: They're coming from the same dataset.
Service Node FC Sort Service Scheduled Manifested Total Forecast Overage Year

1DA-DFW-SNS  DFW FTW9 UPS-NEXT NDA 0 755 759 283 476 2020

NULL  NULL TPA2   UPS-JACFL-N GROUND NULL NULL 8604 0 8604 2019

Comment: can you edit the question tos how what your dataset looks like? and possibly a mock up of what the desired result is?

Comment: @Harry I have edited the question and attached an image of the excel sheet which shows the desired result (the bottom table), and to replicate that formula on Visual Studio, if that makes sense.

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any sort of aggregation.. so the math should be fairly straightforward! (lust like your excel formula but with your field names) .You seem to hard code your column values.. why not just use a Matrix and let that do the work for you?

Comment: @Harry I did figure it out, thank you for your help though! I still do have one more hurdle I'm trying to overcome. I edited the question to show the new challenge I'm facing. Let me know if you do know a way to show multiple parameter values in an expression as asked on the most recent edit of my question – cyriac jacob 18 mins ago   Delete

Comment: Please do not edit the question to a different issue.. all the conversations before this will not make sense anymore.. if you have a new questions.. close this one and ask a a new one